# Scroll to div on input keyup, keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to get the page to scroll to a specific div element when typing into a text input.  The nav has a fixed position and the item.offset().top does output something like 2859, however the page does not scroll. here is the code:

```
$('nav').on('keyup, keydown','input[name=search]',function(){
    var search = $('input[name=search]').val(),
        name = '',
        item = '',
        searchOff = false,
        len = search.length;
    if(len>2){
        $('.products li').each(function(){
            item = $(this);
            name = item.find('p.left').text().substring(0,len).toLowerCase();
            if (name==search && searchOff==false){
                console.log(item.offset().top);
                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:item.offset().top},'slow');
                searchOff=true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `item` doesn't have a `scrollTop` to animate, but `$(window)` does.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yeah, just caught that already updated code, however it is still not scrolling

Comment: Try using .position() instead of .offset()

Comment: [I'm not able to recreate this issue using the general outline of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z58n/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am creating the .products li elements with javascript, do you think that could affect it?

Comment: No, it won't. That would only be a problem if we were binding events to dynamically created elements. When calculating length, and offset values, etc, it isn't a problem. As you indicated yourself, you can see that you are getting the `offset().top` returned to you. That's not going to be the problem. The problem may lay elsewhere, such as within the conditional argument.